# Vue 2 Infinite Loop Across Parent and Child Component Using Slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs-slots

I need to call a method in a child from a parent component. However, something I'm doing in the child component appears to be causing an infinite loop. I've tried looking at other questions, and while they appear to be getting at a similar problem, I can't apply their exact patterns to the issue I'm facing, it appears to be different. I'm just not sure what I'm looking at.

I have 2 components, one called ToggleButtons and another that has been simplified down to a button. Here is ToggleButtons:

```
<template>
    <div role="list">
        <div role="listitem">
            <slot name="left" :is-selected="leftSelected" :toggleLeft="toggle('left')" />
        </div>
        <div role="listitem">
            <slot name="right" :is-selected="rightSelected" :toggleRight="toggle('right')" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: {
            leftSelectedInitially: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true,
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                leftSelected: true,
                rightSelected: false,
            }
        },

        beforeMount() {
            this.leftSelected = this.leftSelectedInitially;
            this.rightSelected = !this.leftSelectedInitially;
        },

        methods: {
            toggle(override) {
                this.leftSelected = override == 'left';
                this.rightSelected = override == 'right';
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

and here is its implementation with the button:

```
<ToggleButtons ref="tb">
    <template v-slot:left="{
        isSelected,
    }">
        <button
            class="button"
            :class="{ secondary: !isSelected }"
            :aria-pressed="isSelected"
            :togglable="true"
            v-text="'left'"
            @click="toggle('left')"
        />
    </template>
    <template v-slot:right="{
        isSelected,
    }">
        <button
            class="button"
            :class="{ secondary: !isSelected }"
            :aria-pressed="isSelected"
            :togglable="true"
            v-text="'right'"
            @click="toggle('right')"
        />
    </template>
</ToggleButtons>
```

where the toggle method is:

```
toggle(direction) {
    this.$refs.tb.toggle(direction);
},
```

As you may already be able to see from leftovers in the code, i've tried various patterns previously, including passing a toggle method through the v-slot. All of these result in the same "you have created an infinite loop" message.

I'm wondering if it's because the method is calling toggle while it's trying to render. I'm not sure if that would actually cause an infinite loop or not. My main problem here is that I don't understand where this loop is coming from. My main goal at this point is to understand what's going wrong, so if it happens again, I'll be able to see it, even if the fix is to just figure out a more simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bindings to the `toggle` function do not make any sense to me:

```
:toggleLeft="toggle('left')"
:toggleRight="toggle('right')
```

Since the function does not return any value, it's simply wrong.

The both bindings cause the function to be called endlessly with `toggle('left')` and `toggle('right')`

Just add `console.log(direction)` to the `toggle` function to see what's going on.

[image: JS Console output]

If you want to get an advice about the right solution, then please describe what you are trying to achieve.

```js
Vue.component('toggle-buttons',{
  props: {
    leftSelectedInitially: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    }
  },
  data() {
      return {
          leftSelected: true,
          rightSelected: false,
      }
  },
  beforeMount() {
      //this.leftSelected = this.leftSelectedInitially;
      //this.rightSelected = !this.leftSelectedInitially;
  },
  methods: {
      toggle(override) {
          console.log(`override: ${override}`)
          this.leftSelected = override == 'left';
          this.rightSelected = override == 'right';
      }
  },
  template: `
<div role="list">
  <div role="listitem">
      <slot name="left" :is-selected="leftSelected" :toggleLeft="toggle('left')" />
  </div>
  <div role="listitem">
      <slot name="right" :is-selected="rightSelected" :toggleRight="toggle('right')" />
  </div>
</div>
`
});

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  methods: {
  toggle(direction) {
    console.log(`direction: ${direction}`)
    this.$refs.tb.toggle(direction);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
<toggle-buttons ref="tb">
    <template v-slot:left="{ isSelected }">
        <button
            class="button"
            :class="{ secondary: !isSelected }"
            :aria-pressed="isSelected"
            :togglable="true"
            v-text="'left'"
            @click="toggle('left')"
        />
    </template>
    <template v-slot:right="{ isSelected }">
        <button
            class="button"
            :class="{ secondary: !isSelected }"
            :aria-pressed="isSelected"
            :togglable="true"
            v-text="'right'"
            @click="toggle('right')"
        />
    </template>
</toggle-buttons>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was trying to pass the method from the child component up into the parent so the parent could trigger it so that only the child is concerned with its data's state. It seems I may be thinking about this problem the wrong way? The problem is that I have 2 toggling buttons in a lot of places throughout my site. I want them to toggle on clicks, but I don't want the parent to have to manage the state, i want the child to do that. Perhaps this is just the wrong approach? (I'm still a cultural noob here, should i edit this into my original question or is a comment fine?)